# Assigning a CNAME to my static-website-bucket in amazon S3 using cloudflare

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I am working on creating a website for my brother (my first website) and have decided to host the whole site through amazon s3. I have done the usual setup so far:

1. Create bucket with the name of the desired domain (www.website.com).
2. Make the bucket a website and assign the index document and error page.
3. upload all of the content and make it public.

The website works fantastic through the bucket endpoint link http://www.website.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Following other tutorials on stackoverflow I then attempted to create a CNAME through my DNS provider. Unfortunately, my domain registrar (1and1.com) would not let me enter the amazon endpoint link saying that the url was too long.

Further down in the comments section of the tutorial I was following was a comment from someone who surpassed this problem by using cloudflare.com.

So, I signed up for cloudflare.com and changed the nameservers via 1and1.com to cloudflare cloudflare ones. After everything propagated I attempted to create a CNAME on cloudflare to the amazon bucket endpoint but i cant get it to work.

How can I get my amazon s3 bucket on my domain name?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen/reviewed these details from our knowledge base? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-

It includes the steps to correctly point at an Amazon S3 bucket. For privacy reasons though, I'd recommend you open a support ticket with CloudFlare directly via https://support.cloudflare.com  so our support team can look at your account's specific details to offer suggestions.

p.s. Disclaimer: I work at CloudFlare.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while since this questions was asked , but as of Jul 2019 if anyone looking for CloudFlare CNAME setup for static website in amazon AWS s3 bucket then please refer screenshot below.

[image]