# Host static web site in Amazon S3 without using Amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to publish a static website in Amazon S3 and after following all the steps I managed to do it, but after a few minutes it didn't work anymore.
I didn't use Amazon Route 53, I just created a CNAME file with my domain provider (http://my.dot.tk/cgi-bin/login01.taloha).
I followed the IP by **host my endpoint** but I saw it changes white often.
I don't want to use Route 53 since is not free, unlike the AWS free usage Tier.

Any clues? May it be Amazon firewall?

Comment: You can use cloudflare DNS for free as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13981496/5253155)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it wont work very well. You would need to create a CNAME record to map to the endpoint, which you can't use for apex records. You would need some other way of forwarding traffic from the apex to presumably `www.domain.com`.

S3, Cloudfront either a set of IPs or Geo-DNS to determine which IP address will serve a given request. This is not something you can efficiently replicate in your own DNS.

The cost of Route53 is pretty low, depending on traffic, it could hit be a $1 or less per month.

Comment: The way I have it now (and it does not work) is with a CNAME record which is Hostname=www.domain.com and IP Address=www.bucket-name.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
I prefer not to use Route 53 since I am just trying and don't intend to pay for my hosting. And because it worked at the beginning and that makes me wonder how to make it work again.

Comment: Make your bucket name same as your website: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-s3-bucket-website-hosting.html 

But even in this case, I am unable to enable SSL and redirect http to https.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  I actually can't use Route53 because of way my employer handles DNS.  It is an ugly solution, but what I did was have a free tier eligible t1.micro ec2 instance with a web server running with a static "elastic ip".  I have my static site in s3, my domain name is pointed at the elastic ip.  The ec2 web-server serves pages that are essentially iframes that contain the desired page from s3.  The html on the ec2 instance looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {       
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
            }       

            #content
            {       
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }       
        </style> 

    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://yoursite.s3-website-zone.amazonaws.com" />
        </div>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

Like I said, it is an ugly solution, but it works with my extremely simple sites.

Answer (score -2):

For static website you can use Cloudflare as FREE option. Cloudflare will act as DNS and CDN for your s3 bucket. More details available here : https://medium.com/@hranicka/hosting-a-static-website-amazon-s3-cloudflare-127b57a13461